# Uploading an image with HTTP Client for Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using HTTP Client - this is a bit of a requirement. I'm having a bit of difficulty uploading an image.

The library is here: https://code.google.com/p/objective-c-http-client/source/checkout

curl -H "x-app-id: APP-ID" -H "x-session-id:SESSION-ID"  -F "image_type=asset_photo" -F upload="@/Users/will/Desktop/test.jpg" "http://endpointurl.com/images"

The curl works. But when I attempt to write the equivalent in HTTP CLIENT, I'm getting a 500 error that's similar to if I have the parameters incorrect.

Here's my request in Objective C

```
MultipartMethod* multiMethod = [[MultipartMethod alloc]initWithContentType:@"multipart/form-data"];
FilePart* filePart = [[FilePart alloc] initWithFile:imageUrl withName:@"upload" compressFile:YES];

[multiMethod addHeader:APP_ID withName:APP_ID_HEADER];
[multiMethod addHeader:sessionId withName:SESSION_ID_HEADER];
[multiMethod addPart:filePart];
[multiMethod addStringPartsFromDictionary:@{@"image_type": @"asset_photo"}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to `AFNetworking`, it is a well known and trusted library to get rid of this kind of problems with iOS.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

If you want a quick overview of how to use it you can read this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial